# Como adicionar um plano de fundo com códigos C#?

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Wellsoft{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
            Console.WriteLine("Software for Wellsoft Games");
            //Valores Inteiros (int)
            int num_1 = 936;
            int num_2 = 5298;
            int num_3 = 323;
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
            Console.WriteLine("Existe " + num_1 + " onlines em nosso site, " + num_2 + " acesso por dia, é " + num_3 + " membros na equipe.");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        }

    }
}
```

Obs: Esse código não tem elementos para adicionar a imagem, só coloquei para entender melhor.

Comment: Você quer adicionar uma imagem em uma aplicação console? Como espera que isto funcione? Você entende o que é um console?

Comment: Ainda não, pois eu sou novato em C#, comecei 3 dias atrás, mal conheço a ferramenta Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Isso não é possível, o máximo que você consegue fazer é mudar a cor do fundo e existe um truque para trocar todo o fundo e não apenas da linha, mas implica em executar um `Console.Clear()`.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGray;
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        Console.Clear();

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```